# showing micro &micro; symbol in a python django template

Tags: python, django

I have some data I am working with i.e displaying it using django on a template. So, the data (NOT from a db) looks like so:

```
<td>{{obj.var1}}</td>
```

and this displays:

```
1.54 \xb5
```

The \xb5 here is for the micro symbol. To display the micro symbol, I wrote a little template tag, which looks like so:

```
....
def search_replace_filter(query):
    return query.replace("\\xb5",r'''&micro;''')
...
```

and this stupidly now displays:

```
1.54 &micro;
```

.. which is not what I want...

Any help would be greatly appreciated :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template interpolation escapes special HTML characters.

You need to [explicitly say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) that the interpretation of a HTML entity is desired.

Comment: urgh! just spent 2 hours trying to figure this out. Thanks! accepted your answer!

Comment: When in doubt, google :) Only when you found out that your problem is reasonably unique, or if you have time to enjoy a puzzle, spend the 2 hours.

Comment: Thanks.. I did google it :( but I guess my keywords betrayed me.. I was using the wrong ones - since I thought it was something to do with decoding :((